# Get the second string in util.format

Tags: node.js

I want this code to return the second string, without the first one:

```
const util = require('util');
util.format('%s', 'foo', 'bar');
```

This will return 'foo'.

You cant print the second string without doing '%s %s', which prints both of them. I only want the second one. How do I do it?

Comment: `util.format('%c%s', 'foo', 'bar')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
util.format('%c%s', 'foo', 'bar')
```